# Best video format for Windows and Mac Compatibility?

Tags: video, media, compatibility, codec

I'm about to encode several videos that will physically distributed to clients running either Windows XP (and upwards) or OS X.

Is there a compressed format that would be playable on both platforms directly without the need to install any codecs. Is this possible or would I need to use WMVs to get any compression on Windows?

Comment: Just to elaborate a little, the file will need to be opened in the filesystem, it won't be played through a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe h264 (mp4) would work on both, just can't guarantee, that WinXP won't need external codecs, you should check it out.

Edit: I was misleaded by the hype of html5. Windows Media Player 9, which comes with WinXP doesn't support playing mp4 without any external software/updates.

Edit 2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245608 - File Formats Supported by Windows Media Player Versions 6.0 and Later